# Calculating EMD for 3D point-clouds is very SLOW

Tags: python, scipy, distance, point-clouds, earth-movers-distance

I wanted to calculate the distance between two 3D point clouds with at least 2000 points using Earth Mover's Distance with the following code, however, it is too slow and does not work properly. So, is there any way to calculate it for approximate it faster?

```
    from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
    from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment

    def emd(self):
        d = cdist(self.X, self.Y)
        assignment = linear_sum_assignment(d)
        return d[assignment].sum() / min(len(self.X), len(self.Y))
```

Comment: Without having details about the kind of dataset we are dealing with here, it's hard to optimize from what you have here. (Provided this is the full code) So please consider providing more details that would aid others in helping you with your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of SciPy 1.4.0 (released December 2019), with the work of [this pull request](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/10296), the implementation of `linear_sum_assignment` is drastically faster. In particular, 2000x2000 geometric instances can be solved in less than 10 seconds on a dated laptop; see some of the benchmarks in the pull request and related threads.

As of SciPy 1.6.0 (released December 2020), there's also `scipy.sparse.csgraph.min_weight_full_bipartite_matching`, which can be used as a drop-in replacement for `linear_sum_assignment`; as the name suggests, it's intended to be used with sparse inputs; yours is of course everything but sparse, and for geometric inputs it will [generally be slower](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/12541#issue-448933999), but in some situations it's worth looking into as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.